# How to find a digit that stands after a keyword

Tags: python, python-re

I have a string with the references. Few references contain an ISBN code, and I need to extract it. I tried this but it is not working in a loop, however, work individually with one string.

Example data:

Qing-An Zeng (October 28, 2015). Wireless Communications, Networking and Applications: Proceedings of WCNA 2014. Springer. ISBN 978-81-322-2580-5.

Dhavale, Sunita Vikrant (March 10, 2017). Advanced Image-Based Spam Detection and Filtering Techniques. Hershey, PA: IGI Global. p. 91. ISBN 9781683180142. Retrieved September 27, 2019.

```
    for line in dftrial['text']:
        line = line.get_text()
        print(type(line))
        search_q = re.findall(r'ISBN (\d+)', line)
        print(search_q)
```

Comment: Please provide a full example that can be tested

Answer (score 0):

The program given below works fine for your problem, it is coded in python3

```
>>> text = ["Qing-An Zeng (October 28, 2015). Wireless Communications, Networking and Applications: Proceedings of WCNA 2014. Springer. ISBN 978-81-322-2580-5.","Dhavale, Sunita Vikrant (March 10, 2017). Advanced Image-Based Spam Detection and Filtering Techniques. Hershey, PA: IGI Global. p. 91. ISBN 9781683180142. Retrieved September 27, 2019."]
>>> for txt in text:
...    x = re.findall("ISBN.[^.]*", txt)
...    print(x)
... 
['ISBN 978-81-322-2580-5']
['ISBN 9781683180142']
```

Comment: ISBN can have 10-13 digits optionally with different groupings of -'s. Stricter regexp would be something like this: `x = re.findall(r'ISBN (\d(?:\d-?){8,11}\d)', txt)`